# How do I save this outlet that used to be attached to a chimney we had removed?

Tags: wiring, receptacle

See photos. This outlet used to be mounted to the chimney in our garage. Our garage has so few outlets so saving this one in the middle is important to us. How do I make this meet code.

I have two thoughts.
Some sort of conduit made to hang? I like this idea since the current conduit tubing is angled due to the drywall and location of the poles. It looks janky. At my work they have outlets hanging from the ceiling in labs but I do not know what they are called or how to google them.

Second idea is to mount to the metal support poles shown that are wrapped in foam. I could use a hose clamp but that looks janky. Screwing it to the pole itself would look better but not sure you want to screw into these support poles.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. The cable has to be protected until it's inside the framing cavity. The box has to be mounted to something stable. That's really it.

Comment: It appears that there's a switch in this box as well. Since there's only one cable in/out of the box, I presume this controls one or both of the outlets?

Comment: VtC for "needs more focus"? Seems pretty focused to me - How do I properly attach this box/conduit so it's not just swinging free. Care to share your thoughts?

Comment: Not clear at what I am asking? I want to mount this electrical box in a more permanent and safe way than ratchet straps. Not sure how I could make that more clear?

Comment: It's not focused because there are a million possible solutions. The question is the textbook definition of open-ended and needs to ask something _specific_.

Comment: @ACD -- the thing that you saw in the labs is called a *pendant* receptacle or box, by the way

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes those are what I <i>was</i> looking for. After seeing their prices I will go with the wood answer.

Answer (score 2):

Mount to the posts, or place a board between the posts (two boards outside the posts clamped to the posts with bolts from board to board, not into the posts, work nicely in the pictured setup with no fear of damaging the posts) and mount to that.

Bend the conduit and drill a hole in the ceiling to provide a proper offset. If that's too daunting, pick up some flexible metal conduit and replace the conduit (this is clearly the "damage preventing sleeve" function given it's NM/B cable in the conduit.) Bending the conduit provides a neater and more finished look.

If number of outlets rather than circuit capacity is your main concern, you could upgrade this to a 4-plex and/or put another box on the other side of the board(s) between the posts.

Comment: I like this idea. Do you have a picture or better description of what hardware to use to clamp two boards? I am picturing two bolts with a nut on each but that seems like it would bend the wood before it would be a strong clamp against the poles.

Comment: Two (or more, but two is enough) carriage bolts (or other bolts, but then you need  two wrenches) placed so they just clear the posts (on the inside unless you want the thing to stick out beyond them.) With any reasonable thickness of wood, it will clamp firmly long before any significant bending takes place.

Comment: Do they make hardware such that it would be flush with the wood board? Have some nice stained wood I could mount it to but wouldn't want nuts or bolts sticking through.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

[image]

From: https://www.familyhandyman.com/article/overhead-electrical-outlets/

Excerpt:
For each overhead electrical outlet you’ll need:

■ A metal electrical box

■ A metal box cover with a center knock-out

■ A strain-relief cord connector

■ Electrical connectors

■ A cord receptacle

■ A short length of stranded-wire electrical cord (buy 12-3 stranded wire for 20-amp circuits and 14-3 for 15-amp circuits).

Answer (score 1):

I would build a wood enclosure around the two poles and paint it white to match the rest of the garage. I wouldn't bother with drywall - use plywood instead as it won't cost much and will be a lot easier than finishing drywall (flat spaces are easy, this is all corners) and it will protect everything inside.

Run the cable inside the enclosure so that you don't need conduit. You can reuse the metal box and mount it on the outside or you can mount a regular box inside with the receptacles/switch on a regular cover plate on the surface.